# Lambda Function Cors Error With Sam Template File

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have a `template.yml` for my lambda function. I have already added Cors configuration for my lambda function. I have checked from AWS console and I added image to above.[image: Gateway AWS Console]

```
  DenemeApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'GET, OPTIONS'"
        AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
  DenemeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: DenemeFunction
      Handler: com.proton.protonservices.controller.UserController::deneme
      Runtime: java11
      CodeUri: .
      MemorySize: 512
      Role: !GetAtt CreateUserRole.Arn
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        DenemeApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /deneme
            Method: GET
            RestApiId:
              Ref: DenemeApi
```

When I send a GET request from my React application, I get the following CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://72cfs1x8z0.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/deneme' from origin 'http://localhost:6161' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

and

> GET https://72cfs1x8z0.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/deneme net::ERR_FAILED

[image: From Chrome Console]

Sam file should we change or do I have an error in a different place?

Comment: What does the full error message say? Edit your question and add it (as text, not as a picture) there.

Comment: I have just edited @jub0bs

Comment: _Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response._ This indicates that you're including a header named `access-control-allow-origin` to your request, which doesn't make sense because it's a _response_ header. Drop that header from your request.

Comment: You're right I changed. But I have added some response header to my lambda function Response type. How I can do it for all APIs ?